# React Bootstrap - how to animate ProgressBar when value is increasing but not when resetting to 0%?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

I'm using the [React Bootstrap ProgresBar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/) component with animation turned on. In the current behavior, animation works both when increasing and decreasing the progress. I have a use-case where I slowly increase the progress from 0 to 100, and then I reset the progress back to 0 and increase it slowly again. When resetting from 100 to 0 the progress animates backwards which is very confusing for my users.

The desirable behavior is: animate when (gradually) increasing from 0 to 100, but don't animate when resetting from 100 to 0.

Anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: There is property called `animated` you need to change that according to your needs.

Comment: I'm using `animated`, but is there a way to "tell" it to animate only when progress increases but not when progress decreases?

Comment: Use a wrapper component

Comment: can you describe how?

Comment: Create your own compoent which uses this progressbar compnent which takes the `now` as a prop and then pass it react bootstrap compoenent. Now change animated according to the passed prop `now`

Comment: the `animated` prop only animates the stripes, it doesn't animate the progress itself. So this solution won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution as posted in this [issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/4981#issuecomment-584240544):

Just add this to the component CSS:

```css
.progress-bar[aria-valuenow="0"] {
    transition: none;
}
```

When the `now` value changes to 0 the transition is set to none and the bar immediately disappears. Only works with zero though, if you go from 80 to 30 you still see the transition.